# Unix egrep command how to create a pattern to match the following?

Tags: regex, unix, command-line, grep, pattern-matching

I want to ask about back reference in egrep.

I have a file, it contains:

> aa aa someothertext
>
> and there are something like 77 77

How do I use back reference to match the pattern 'aa aa' and '77 77'?

I tried:

```
egrep '(aa )\1' file.txt
```

and it will match 'aa aa'. Then. I tried to replace 'aa' with ' ([a-zA-Z0-9])\1', which yields:

```
egrep '(([a-zA-Z0-9])\1 )\1' file.txt
```

It won't work.

I'd appreciate if you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that capturing groups are indexed by their opening parenthesis: you were calling the first group before it was defined.

In `((a)b)`, `\1` is referring to `(a)b` and  `\2` to `a`.

To fix this, you can use the correct index:

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9])\2 )\1
```

Comment: Its unclear if the pattern is "xx xx" or "xx xx ". If you want to match the first, then it's `((a-zA-Z0-9])\2) \1`.

Comment: @Robin Thanks! Now I get what does \n means.. totally!

Comment: Glad I could help. @MarkLakata: True. Since the first example (`(aa )\1`) seemed to have done the job I didn't modify the regex though.